# How to create a centered div with max-width

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I want to place all my content within a div that's centered, but has a max width so that the content doesn't expand to be too wide on large screens. Something like this

[image]

I thought this would work using [`flex`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/flex) + [`justify-center`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/justify-content) + [`max-w-lg`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/max-width), but it does not.

```
<main class="pt-20">
  <div class='flex justify-center max-w-lg'>
    <h2 class="text-5xl font-semibold tracking-tight text-center text-gray-700">
      A Cool Title
    </h2>
    <p class="mt-8 text-sm text-center text-gray-700">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
  </div>
</main>
```

[image]

(Tested at https://play.tailwindcss.com/)

Comment: Dunno about tailwind syntax, but `main` should do the centering of its content...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `flex-col` to make the center becomes vertical and `mx-auto` so that it has horizontal margins:

```
<main class="pt-20">
  <div class='flex justify-center max-w-lg flex-col mx-auto'>
    <h2 class="text-5xl font-semibold tracking-tight text-center text-gray-700">
      A Cool Title
    </h2>
    <p class="mt-8 text-sm text-center text-gray-700">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
  </div>
</main>
```